# Bootstrap Modal immediately closes when showing on edit form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

i need some help, i have already read a lot of articles but haven't found de solution to my problem.

[As you can see in the picture my modal button is in a table but when i click de edit button it shows de modal with the edit form but it closes inmmediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOCFQ.png)

These is my code of my button, im using php and bootstrap:

```
echo "<td><a href='consultar_usuario.php?id_trabajador=$arreglo[0]&idactualizar=3'><img src='../imagenes/Iconos/actualiza.png' class='img-rounded' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></td>";
```

and these is the code of my modal:

```
echo'
  <div class="control-group modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Modificar Empleado</h3>
            </div>
           <form action="../validar_form/valida_actualizacion.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal modal-body">
```

all the divs and form are close in my proyect.

I really apreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion hope this helps somehow.

this line:

```
echo "<td><a href='consultar_usuario.php?id_trabajador=$arreglo[0]&idactualizar=3'><img src='../imagenes/Iconos/actualiza.png' class='img-rounded' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'></td>";
```

can you change it to this:

```
echo "<td><a href='consultar_usuario.php?id_trabajador=$arreglo[0]&idactualizar=3'><img src='../imagenes/Iconos/actualiza.png' class='img-rounded modal_clicker'></td>";
```

and add this javascript:

```
<script>
 $(".modal_clicker").on("click", function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

That way you can just echo the "modal_clicker" and not repeating the "data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'" over and over again.

And for your question I hope this code helps:

```
<script>
 $("#myModal").modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false})
</script>
```

[ Fixed / Solution ]

I found what's causing it. Your are trying to open a new url everytime you click the link; here `<a href='consultar_usuario.php?id_trabajador=$arreglo[0]&idactualizar=3'>`

The fix for this is to change your href or link into this.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>
```

If you want to access these: id_trabajador=$arreglo[0]&idactualizar='3'

try adding this to your link as data-*. See example below.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class="modal_clicker" data-id_trabajador='".$arreglo[0]."' data-idactualizar=3'>
```

You can then access those data-* using the javascript below:

```
$(".modal_clicker").on("click", function(){
 var ele = $(this);
 var id_trabajador = ele.attr("data-id_trabajador"); 
 var idactualizar= ele.attr("data-idactualizar"); 
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Hi, i follow your suggestion but it didn't work could i send you my file maybe my php code is affecting the modal class.

Comment: These is the link were you can download the code file that im using https://mega.nz/#!ChJnBRLK

Comment: Can't download, it's asking for "key". Did you try disable the form submit right? I'm thinking that your using ajax to submit data. try this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jeorlie/136ucea8/1/  I disable the modal close when click outside the content. It would be nice I we can see your code.

Comment: Sorry about that link whith key, here it is the link with out the key https://mega.nz/#!ChJnBRLK!ZWYAniosWqMvw3p8lIsiJZ-DzKgG_m7OKnw7_GowrZs

Comment: hi I edited my answer above.. see the edits below Fixed: have a great day. I thought you have disable the your link button's default action but when I saw your code I then found out the cause of your problem.